# How to start modify all Azure Data Factory Triggers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

The following code will stop all Azure Data Factory triggers:

```
$triggersADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Stop-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
```

However, what I thought would restart all the Triggers doesn't appear to work:

```
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
```

I get the following error:

```
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.name -Force }
True
Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
Error Code: BadRequest
Error Message: Missing or invalid pipeline references for trigger Trigger_az4
Request Id: 08b0e51a-9a3d-4662-ba8c-8ea62279c558
Timestamp (Utc):10/21/2019 21:05:10
At line:3 char:33
+ ... ch-Object { Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $Resource ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.StartAzureDataFactoryTriggerCommand

Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
Error Code: BadRequest
Error Message: Missing or invalid pipeline references for trigger Trigger_c2l
Request Id: 86a0199d-5399-4079-abd4-7fe6973df222
Timestamp (Utc):10/21/2019 21:05:11
At line:3 char:33
+ ... ch-Object { Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $Resource ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.StartAzureDataFactoryTriggerCommand
```

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the ARM template, the payload of trigger has a property called pipeline. For scheduled trigger it should be 'pipelines'. Refer the json of the trigger from the UI, and you will see that it should be an array of pipelines, not a single pipeline.

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I saw your answer to this question on one other forum, however,  I don't see the property called pipeline

Comment: The ARM templeate doesnt have a property called pipeline for the the scheduled trigger, see following code ```{
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/Trigger_c2l')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "annotations": [],
                "runtimeState": "Stopped",
                "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
                "typeProperties": {```

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop the triggers you will need to change the Azure Powershell Inline:script task to Preview 4, see image.
[image]

The following code will restart the Triggers;

```
#Triggers 

    $triggersADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName 

$DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
        $triggersTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers" }
        $triggerNames = $triggersTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
        $activeTriggerNames = $triggersTemplate | Where-Object { $_.properties.runtimeState -eq "Started" -and ($_.properties.pipelines.Count -gt 0 -or $_.properties.pipeline.pipelineReference -ne $null)} | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
        $deletedtriggers = $triggersADF | Where-Object { $triggerNames -notcontains $_.Name }
        $triggerstostop = $triggerNames | where { ($triggersADF | Select-Object name).name -contains $_ }


    if ($predeployment -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Starting active triggers"
        $activeTriggerNames | ForEach-Object { 
            Write-host "Enabling trigger " $_
            Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_ -Force 
        }
    }

The answers came directly from Microsoft. The code can be found at the official site for CI/CD for Azure Data Factory here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#update-active-triggers
```

I hope this helps.